# Add sequence of datetime for each level of factor

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a factor column:

```
 s<- data.frame( id = 901:910)
 s$id<-as.factor(s$id)
```

and I have a sequence of datetime:

```
library(lubridate)
start <- now()+as.difftime(2,units="hours")
t <- seq(from = start, length.out = 60, by = "mins")
```

I'd like to add the sequence `t` as a column in `s` for each level of `s$id`.

Comment: Perhaps `expand.grid(id=s$id,time=t)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to `expand.grid(id = s$id, time = t)`, you could also use the `CJ` (Cross Join) of the `data.table` package:

```
CJ(s$id,t)
```

which gives:

```
      V1                  V2
  1: 901 2015-09-19 14:52:23
  2: 901 2015-09-19 14:53:23
  3: 901 2015-09-19 14:54:23
  4: 901 2015-09-19 14:55:23
  5: 901 2015-09-19 14:56:23
 ---                        
596: 910 2015-09-19 15:47:23
597: 910 2015-09-19 15:48:23
598: 910 2015-09-19 15:49:23
599: 910 2015-09-19 15:50:23
600: 910 2015-09-19 15:51:23
```

When you want to add that to `s`, you can do the following join operation:

```
s <- setDT(s, key="id")[CJ(s$id,t)]
```

which gives:

```
> s
      id                  V2
  1: 901 2015-09-19 15:08:39
  2: 901 2015-09-19 15:09:39
  3: 901 2015-09-19 15:10:39
  4: 901 2015-09-19 15:11:39
  5: 901 2015-09-19 15:12:39
 ---                        
596: 910 2015-09-19 16:03:39
597: 910 2015-09-19 16:04:39
598: 910 2015-09-19 16:05:39
599: 910 2015-09-19 16:06:39
600: 910 2015-09-19 16:07:39
```

---

Another option is to use the `crossing`-function from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
crossing(id = s$id, time = t)
```

which gives a similar result.

Comment: perfect thanks, which one of both method is more efficient

Comment: @datashinobi In this case the base R approach is faster for a dataframe with less than 1000 id's. For much bigger datasets, the `data.table` approach is faster.